# Is there Highcharts v5 reference available somewhere?

Tags: highcharts

As of moment of writing this, https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/ only offers reference documentation for v6.0.7 (which is the current one).

Is there any way to get v5.x.x reference somewhere?